# Is there any way to replace a Map value inside a List using java 8?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8

I have the below piece of code. I need to replace the Map's value based on the key,value that i have already.

Definition class has the below variables:

```
private Map<String, String> rows;
private String tableName;
```

I have tried with the below code. Can this be achieved in any other simpler way?

```
/*Definitions*/
Definition definitionObj = new Definition();
definitionObj.setTableName("TABLE1");
Map map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("1","one");
map.put("2","two");
map.put("3","threee");
definitionObj.setRows(map);

Definition definitionObj1 = new Definition();
definitionObj1.setTableName("TABLE2");
Map map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
map1.put("4","one");
map1.put("5","two");
map1.put("6","threee");
definitionObj1.setRows(map1);

String key1 = "2";
String value1 = "modifiedvalue"; /*the value that i need to set*/

List<Definition> myList = Arrays.asList(definitionObj,definitionObj1);

Definition result1 = myList.stream()                       
        .filter(x -> "TABLE1".equals(x.getTableName()))        
        .findAny()                                     
        .orElse(null);
result1.getRows().replace(key1,value1);
System.out.println(result1);
```

Comment: I think a for loop would be simpler than your stream. Also, don't operate on potentially null pointers.

Comment: I believe you are using non-standard classes here. `Definition` seems to not be part of Java 8. It might be a library. If so, please let us know which one, so we can help.

Comment: DefinitionClass:
public class Definition implements Serializable {
private Map<String, String> rows;
private String tableName;
public Map<String, String> getRows() {
return rows;}
public void setRows(Map<String, String> rows) {
this.rows = rows;}
public String getTableName() {
return tableName;
}
public void setTableName(String tableName) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Definition{" +
           "rows=" + rows +
           ", tableName='" + tableName + '\'' +
           '}';
}
}

Comment: what if `result1` or `result1.getRows` is null in the code while you perform a `replace`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `findAny` method returns an optional which you can map to a dictionary and then use `ifPresent` to update the dictionary value for a given key. Here's how it looks.

```
myList.stream().filter(x -> "TABLE1".equals(x.getTableName()))
    .findAny().map(Definition::getRows)
    .ifPresent(m -> m.put(key1, value1));
```

Apart from that, your `Map` declaration should be changed to use parameterized types instead of raw types. Change it like so,

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

However, a much better approach would be to declare a new API method in your `Definition` class to update the internal state given the required parameters and then use it in your client code. Here's how it looks.

```
public void updateRows(String key, String value) {
    if (rows.containsKey(key))
        rows.put(key, value);
}

myList.stream().filter(x -> "TABLE1".equals(x.getTableName())).findAny()
                .ifPresent(d -> d.updateRows(key1, value1));
```

While the former violates encapsulation, the latter doesn't.